# The cluster-info ConfigMap does not yet contain a JWS signature for token ID "cjxj26"

Tags: kubernetes

I have a master node, now I want to join the master node from a work node, I generated a never expiry token and execute join command, however I got this error:

```
[root@worker-node1 ~]# kubeadm join 192.168.18.136:6443 --token cjxj26.ibwrtisae30ypis6 \
```

> --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:2659517cbbb2623b3d93408a4ab50f3592a3d021adf25d25c8050dd44345eadd
> [preflight] Running pre-flight checks
> [WARNING IsDockerSystemdCheck]: detected "cgroupfs" as the Docker cgroup driver. The recommended driver is "systemd". Please follow the guide at https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/cri/
> [WARNING Hostname]: hostname "worker-node1" could not be reached
> [WARNING Hostname]: hostname "worker-node1": lookup worker-node1 on 192.168.18.2:53: no such host
> ^C
> [root@worker-node1 ~]# kubeadm join 192.168.18.136:6443 --token cjxj26.ibwrtisae30ypis6 --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:2659517cbbb2623b3d93408a4ab50f3592a3d021adf25d25c8050dd44345eadd --v=5
> I0714 22:05:12.684249    1567 join.go:395] [preflight] found NodeName empty; using OS hostname as NodeName
> I0714 22:05:12.684489    1567 initconfiguration.go:104] detected and using CRI socket: /var/run/dockershim.sock
> [preflight] Running pre-flight checks
> I0714 22:05:12.684592    1567 preflight.go:90] [preflight] Running general checks
> I0714 22:05:12.684742    1567 checks.go:249] validating the existence and emptiness of directory /etc/kubernetes/manifests
> I0714 22:05:12.684758    1567 checks.go:286] validating the existence of file /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf
> I0714 22:05:12.684768    1567 checks.go:286] validating the existence of file /etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf
> I0714 22:05:12.684776    1567 checks.go:102] validating the container runtime
> I0714 22:05:12.844191    1567 checks.go:128] validating if the "docker" service is enabled and active
> [WARNING IsDockerSystemdCheck]: detected "cgroupfs" as the Docker cgroup driver. The recommended driver is "systemd". Please follow the guide at https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/cri/
> I0714 22:05:13.064741    1567 checks.go:335] validating the contents of file /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables
> I0714 22:05:13.064849    1567 checks.go:335] validating the contents of file /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
> I0714 22:05:13.064905    1567 checks.go:649] validating whether swap is enabled or not
> I0714 22:05:13.064948    1567 checks.go:376] validating the presence of executable conntrack
> I0714 22:05:13.064986    1567 checks.go:376] validating the presence of executable ip
> I0714 22:05:13.065010    1567 checks.go:376] validating the presence of executable iptables
> I0714 22:05:13.065033    1567 checks.go:376] validating the presence of executable mount
> I0714 22:05:13.065057    1567 checks.go:376] validating the presence of executable nsenter
> I0714 22:05:13.065082    1567 checks.go:376] validating the presence of executable ebtables
> I0714 22:05:13.065104    1567 checks.go:376] validating the presence of executable ethtool
> I0714 22:05:13.065127    1567 checks.go:376] validating the presence of executable socat
> I0714 22:05:13.065149    1567 checks.go:376] validating the presence of executable tc
> I0714 22:05:13.065167    1567 checks.go:376] validating the presence of executable touch
> I0714 22:05:13.065199    1567 checks.go:520] running all checks
> I0714 22:05:13.262576    1567 checks.go:406] checking whether the given node name is reachable using net.LookupHost
> [WARNING Hostname]: hostname "worker-node1" could not be reached
> [WARNING Hostname]: hostname "worker-node1": lookup worker-node1 on 192.168.18.2:53: no such host
> I0714 22:05:14.338418    1567 checks.go:618] validating kubelet version
> I0714 22:05:14.465098    1567 checks.go:128] validating if the "kubelet" service is enabled and active
> I0714 22:05:14.485740    1567 checks.go:201] validating availability of port 10250
> I0714 22:05:14.486043    1567 checks.go:286] validating the existence of file /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
> I0714 22:05:14.486068    1567 checks.go:432] validating if the connectivity type is via proxy or direct
> I0714 22:05:14.486125    1567 join.go:465] [preflight] Discovering cluster-info
> I0714 22:05:14.486182    1567 token.go:78] [discovery] Created cluster-info discovery client, requesting info from "192.168.18.136:6443"
> I0714 22:05:14.624417    1567 token.go:221] [discovery] **The cluster-info ConfigMap does not yet contain a JWS signature for token ID "cjxj26"**, will try again
> I0714 22:05:20.278283    1567 token.go:221] [discovery] The cluster-info ConfigMap does not yet contain a JWS signature for token ID "cjxj26", will try again
> I0714 22:05:26.320259    1567 token.go:221] [discovery] The cluster-info ConfigMap does not yet contain a JWS signature for token ID "cjxj26", will try again

actually, the token is exist, when I execute kubeadm token list in the master node, it can display:

```
   [root@k8s-master ~]# kubeadm token list
TOKEN                     TTL         EXPIRES   USAGES                   DESCRIPTION                                                EXTRA GROUPS
cjxj26.ibwrtisae30ypis6   <forever>   <never>   authentication,signing   <none>                                                     system:bootstrappers:kubeadm:default-node-token
```

and the token was exist in the cluster-info configmap.

```
[root@k8s-master .kube]# kubectl -n kube-public get cm cluster-info -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  jws-kubeconfig-cjxj26: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImNqeGoyNiJ9..RgWG119Onf5oZLgCS0MPfIjcshdhm81bUz_mTq1Av54
  kubeconfig: |
    apiVersion: v1
    clusters:
    - cluster:
```

Did anyone get this kind of error before? I tried to search solutions in google, many people said re-generate token, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Have you tried doing this https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/335#issuecomment-363225920 or this https://discuss.kubernetes.io/t/cluster-info-configmap-does-not-yet-contain-a-jws-signature/14985?

Comment: still not working, thanks for your post.

Comment: Where is token in your cluster info?

Comment: @EvenChen I post an answer, please review it, and if it is correct, please accept that

Answer (score 8):

Maybe your problem, is from token timed out.

If you want to sure this problem exist you can run below command

```
kubeadm token list
```

If above command does not show anything, your problem is token is timed out.

for resolve your problem, you can do below

```
kubeadm token create
```

If you run `kubeadm token list` again you can see below result

```
TOKEN                     TTL         EXPIRES                USAGES                   DESCRIPTION                                                EXTRA GROUPS
70jkdh.gx9oiqd7jno56nou   23h         2021-10-25T19:52:59Z   authentication,signing   <none>                                                     system:bootstrappers:kubeadm:default-node-token
```

As you can see this token has TTL, so after 23h this token was expired.

So before the TTL has comes, you can join another node with result token of above command.

Comment: `kubeadm token create --print-join-command` this will output the command that you need to run on the worker nodes in order to join the cluster with the new token you created

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the error was in the controller-manager, not in the api server logs.
Check the logs of the ...-controller-manager-... pod in the kube-system namespace:

```
kubectl get pod -n kube-system
kubectl logs -n kube-system <name-of-the-pod>
```

Mine was full of error about an invalid certificate (wrong ip address).

Comment: Yes, this error is always caused when the `controller-manager` is not running successfully. Mine was  `--pod-eviction-timeout` argument which is no longer supported in Kubernetes `v1.27.4` .

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting a similar issue using Kubespray. I haven't discovered something relevant to share yet but did you check errors in the `apiserver`, `controller-manager` and `etcd` services?

UPDATE: I just discovered that disabling the cloud-node-lifecycle controller was the root cause of my issue. Don't do this in a multi-node setup.

```yaml
kube_kubeadm_controller_extra_args:
  controllers: "*,-cloud-node-lifecycle"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check "kubelet-api-server" logs, when create new token for joining new node. It will create a token JWS signature in cluster-info configmap. This is due to kubelet-api-server pod error that the token not updated in cluster-info. To resolve this issue, you first check kubelet-api-server pod, and make sure it works, no error in it.